# Troubleshoot Arduino LCD 16 x 2 shield

Tags: lcd

I tried to assemble Adafruit's Arduino LCD 16 x 2 using the instructions [RGB LCD Shield: Control a 16x2 Character LCD using 2 pins - Assembly](https://learn.adafruit.com/rgb-lcd-shield/assembly)  without any success.

After assembly, I uploaded the [HelloWorld example sketch](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-RGB-LCD-Shield-Library) on to the Arduino. The shield doesn't seem to be working. The LCD didn't turn on.

If I push back/press the LCD it turn on. Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please upload the picture of your completed board.

Comment: Where have the photos disappeared to? Where they lost when the answer  that you posted was deleted? If so, could you edit your question and add the photos there? It may help other people who are having the same issue as you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By visually assessing the pictures, the issue seems to be due to poor soldering job.

You should try re-heating the soldering joints and make sure they are clean. There could be dry joints that may not be conducting signals.

Also you should upload pictures to your question post, not as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Chetan. I reheated some of the soldering joints and its started working. Thanks again! Feeling like a champ!

Comment: @user1261620 I'm glad that my post helped you in fixing the board. Before investing in expensive kits, you can practice soldering on some cheap scrap boards.